# Variables in response is undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have an issue that keeps bugging the hell our of me I was hoping that someone could help me "level up" a bit.
I have this function in a service:

```
this.getChatStreams = function(callback) {
    $http.get(envService.read('apiUrl') + '/messaging/chat')
      .then(function(response) {
        callback(response);
      }).catch(function(response) {
        callback(response);
      });
  };
```

Now that works, yes I'm aware I can do some nicer error handling. However in my call back:

```
chatService.getChatStreams(function(response) {
  $scope.emptychat = true;
  if (response.data.conv !== null) {
    $scope.emptychat = false;
    $scope.chats = response.data.conv;
    startChat();
  }
});
```

I get an error in the console:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating `response.data.conv`)

`response.data.conv` however is null, but not undefined - so what am I doing wrong?

/Peter

Comment: You should use promises instead of callbacks.

Comment: Please create afiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

```
var response= $.parseJSON(response);
```

and access

Answer (score 0):

Why not just run:

```
  if (response.data.conv) {
```

That way you check both null and undefined, rather than just if null?

Comment: There is no reason to write `response.data.conv && response.data.conv !== null`